# how do i use index_number and date_of_birth for frontend login in laravel with the user having to register first

Tags: laravel

I am creating a student project in Laravel. I have created all my models including the student model. I want to use the student_number(index_number) and the students date_of_birth from the student model as login credential for the front end view instead of the default user login(email and password). I do not want users to register before they can login as in the default laravel welcome page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many tricks to do this.

**Laravel** ships with [Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication)

In your **Login Controller** you can do this:

```
public function login() {
  $user = User::where('index_number', request('index_number'))->first();
  if($user->birthday != request('birthday')) {
    return 'Invalid Credentials';
  }

  \Auth::login($user);

  return 'login success'
}
```

Comment: do i have to create another table for the front-end authentication because i already have adminsTable for the backend authentication @code for money

Comment: @eons be careful using that trick you need to hash any of the authentication methods you use.

Comment: its student project, what i means is since i have the studentsTable in the admin area is there a way to transfer its content to the usersTable

Answer (score 0):

Try Auth::attempt() method,
pass your credentials same as your user table.
for example;

```
public function login(Request $request) 
{
    $credentials = ['student_number' => $request->student_number,'date_of_birth' => $request->date_of_birth,'active' => 'Y'];//Database to check in User table
    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        return redirect('student/dashboard');
    }
    else
    {
        Session::flash('mess', "Invalid Credentials , Please try again.");
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

Don't forgot to use

```
use Auth;
```

Hope this works